# Scala Play ReactiveMongo - Arbitrary list of query parameters

Tags: scala, playframework, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

I'm trying to support arbitrary filters for a REST API that fetches a list of documents from MongoDB.
For instance

- //example.com/users <- list all
- //example.com/users?age=30 <- all users who are 30
- //example.com/users?age=30&name=John <- all users who are 30 and called John
- ...

I'm using Play-ReactiveMongo and dealing with JSONCollection objects only.

So in my routes I put

```
GET   /users        controllers.Users.list(id: Option[String], name: Option[String], age: Option[Int])
```

But there are two problem with that, first I'll need to have a pretty long list of optional parameters, and then in my controller I need to use pattern matching on all of them to check whether they're empty or not, and also build the selector that I use to filter my collection.

```
var filters = JsObject(Nil)
name match {
  case Some(x) => filters += ("name" -> JsString(x))
  case None => None
}
```

I realized that I can get the full query string from the request object, which is a Map[String, Seq[String]]. But then I don't know a good way to check whether values are String or something else.

Is there another better and idiomatic way to do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution can be:

1. Use POST instead of GET:
   **POST** /example.com/users
   "data"={"age":25, "name":"xyz", ... }
2. OR single param in GET:
   **GET** /example.com/users?filter={"age":25, "name":"xyz", ... }

On the server side, just validate against your model class OR just pass the same json in your reactivemongo find method.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe request binders will help you to create complex objects from varying request parameters.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaRequestBinders#QueryStringBindable

For example, you could build something like this (from the docs):

```
case class AgeRange(from: Int, to: Int)
```

for requests like this:

```
/age?from=1&to=10
```

Now you could change these attributes to Option and create a function that creates a reactivemongo query based on the values at hand.